# Fancybox 2 fails to show AJAX content ("The requested content cannot be loaded.")

Tags: ajax, fancybox

I have this fairly basic code within a $(document).ready listener:

```
        $('#contact-us-button').fancybox({
            padding: 20,
            beforeLoad: function () {
                            $("#slideshow").data('nivoslider').stop();
                        },
            afterClose: function () {
                            $("#slideshow").data('nivoslider').start();
                        }
        });

        $('.get-a-quote').fancybox({
            padding: 20,
            beforeLoad: function () {
                            $("#slideshow").data('nivoslider').stop();
                        },
            afterClose: function () {
                            $("#slideshow").data('nivoslider').start();
                        }
        });
```

Whereas  the HTML:

```
 <a id="contact-us-button" href="impianto/get-a-quote-form.php"></a>
```

[...]

```
 <div class="product">
<h1>Ferrari California</h1>
<a href="dettaglio.php?id=7">
<img src="images/showcase/ferrari-california-showcase.jpg" />
</a>
<a class="get-a-quote" href="impianto/get-a-quote-form.php?id=7"></a>
 </div>
```

Fancybox binds correctly but shows that message in place of my form. There are no conflicts among class names and IDs. Any ideas? Please note that Fancybox 1.3.4 behaves correctly with about the same code (different options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `fancybox.ajax` class to your links like

```
<a id="contact-us-button" class="fancybox.ajax" href="impianto/get-a-quote-form.php"></a>
```

and

```
<a class="get-a-quote fancybox.ajax" href="impianto/get-a-quote-form.php?id=7"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the property 'type' : 'iframe' if you want it to show another web page's content inside it like a window to the other page.

Something like this in your  < head > tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                'type'          : 'iframe'
            });
        });
</script>
```

Also it might be obvious but if not... With this specific javascript enabling "fancybox" class links as popup links, your link to fire a popup would have class set as matching the class name in the javascript above, something like:

```
<a href="webpage_URL_to_show_in_popup.php" class="fancybox">Link</a>
```